# Add dropdown list to woocommerce cart and retrieve value on checkout?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'd like to modify `cart.php` to contain a dropdown list of "checkout agents" and then retrieve that data when checking out to redirect to the correct agent (different URLs).

I already have `cart.php` in the child theme.   I have created a `cart-custom-checkout.php` page to handle retrieving the cart contents and redirecting (wp_redirect) to an agents URL (I tested a single agent by building the URL from the cart contents and it works great).

I enabled the custom checkout via modifying the child theme `functions.php` as follows:

```
// enable custom checkout for woocommerce
add_shortcode( 'cart_custom_checkout', 'cart_custom_checkout_function' );
function cart_custom_checkout_function() {
        wc_get_template('cart/cart-custom-checkout.php');
}
```

Then used that shortcode on the `checkout page`.

Now that everything works like I want in concept, the final step is to create the dropdown list in the `cart.php` so one of several agents can be chosen.  From there I then need to somehow retrieve that in the `cart-custom-checkout.php` page.   If it were part of the WC() cart data or something like that would be great.

Can someone help explain how I can do what I'm wanting to do?

TIA!!

**Update:**  I've gone a little further and added my dropddown list as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_totals', 'woocommerce_cart_add_resellers');
function woocommerce_cart_add_resellers() {
    wc_get_template('cart/cart-add-reseller.php');
}
```

The `cart-add-reseller.php` contents are:

```
<div style="margin-top:5px">
    <select name="agent">
    <option value="Agent1">Use Agent1</option>
    <option value="Agent2">Use Agent2</option>  
    </select>
</div>
```

Now just need to get what `agent` value is in the `cart-custom-checkout.php` page.   How do I do that?

**Update2**:  I am not getting any `$_POST` data when clicking the `proceeded to checkout` button.

```
// enable custom checkout for woocommerce
add_shortcode( 'cart_custom_checkout', 'cart_custom_checkout_function' );
function cart_custom_checkout_function() {
    var_dump($_POST);
    wc_get_template('cart/cart-custom-checkout.php');
}
```

It's empty.

**Update 3:** I've check `$post` which just gives me the checkout page itself with the shortcode in it, `$_POST` is empty, `$_SESSIONS` is empty, `$_GET` is empty.   I'm not sure where the `$_POST` data went, maybe some javascript or something like that which I know nothing about.  If I could just know a filter or action or something to give me the `$_POST` data, it will have the value I need.  So I give up for now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I fully understand what you have, if you were to add the following in functions.php, it will add the required field to the cart page and allow it to be accessible via $_POST on the checkout page. This essential replaces the default Proceed to Checkout button, with a new one that includes the select field and a post action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'add_agent_before_proceed_to_checkout', 15 );
function add_agent_before_proceed_to_checkout() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
?>
    <form id="checkout_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url ( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>">
        <div style="margin-top:5px">
            <select name="agent">
                <option value selected="selected">-- Select an Agent --</option>
                <option value="Agent1">Use Agent1</option>
                <option value="Agent2">Use Agent2</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" style="width:100%;"><?php
esc_html_e( 'Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce' ) ?></button>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

The reason what you had added to cart didn't work, is the Proceed to Checkout button (woocommerce\templates\cart\proceed-to-checkout-button.php) by default doesn't do a post action, it is actually a link. Also the spot you were adding your input was not within a form so wouldn't have posted the value.

Comment: That works just as I wanted thanks.   Now how do I save the selected value so when the user updates the cart quantity it will retain the chosen item in the dropdown list.  As it is now, it resets to the first one again.

Comment: I have a new question about retaining the contents of the select dropdown list at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856979/retain-woocommerce-cart-custom-select-field-on-quantity-change if you can help.